# Neo4jClient does not add properties to a relationship

Tags: c#, neo4j, neo4jclient

We have been trying to write a C# client that seeds a Neo4j instance with some nodes and relationships. We are facing probelms when trying to create relationship properties.

Here is the code to create the relatioship with the flag property:

```
var s = clientConnection.CreateRelationship(root, new RelationshipPrincipleToContent("SECURITY", rootFolder) { flags = "+W" });
```

Here is the relationship class:

```
public class RelationshipPrincipleToContent : Relationship, IRelationshipAllowingSourceNode<Principles>, IRelationshipAllowingTargetNode<Content>{
    public string flags { get; set; }
    string RelationshipName;

    public RelationshipPrincipleToContent(NodeReference targetNode) : base(targetNode){}

    public RelationshipPrincipleToContent(string RelationshipName, NodeReference targetNode): base(targetNode){
        this.RelationshipName = RelationshipName;
    }

    public override string RelationshipTypeKey{
        get { return RelationshipName; }
    }
}
```

When we look at the data in the data browser tab there are no properties on the relationships. We have also created a relationship index?

What are we missing/ doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly add a class (PayLoad.cs in this instance) that holds a set for a public string.

```
 public class PayLoad
    {
        public string Comment { get; set; }
    }
```

Update your relationship class to use this PayLoad class:

```
public class RelationshipPrincipleToContent : Relationship<PayLoad>, IRelationshipAllowingSourceNode<Principles>, IRelationshipAllowingTargetNode<Content>
    {
        string RelationshipName;

        public RelationshipPrincipleToContent(string RelationshipName, NodeReference targetNode, PayLoad pl)
            : base(targetNode, pl)
        {
            this.RelationshipName = RelationshipName;
        }

        public override string RelationshipTypeKey
        {
            get { return RelationshipName; }
        }
    }
}
```

Now just update your method call on the relationship class:

```
clientConnection.CreateRelationship(AllPrincipals, new RelationshipPrincipleToContent("SECURITY", rootFolder, new PayLoad() { Comment = "+R" }));
```

Answer (score 2):

(Context: I lead the Neo4jClient project.)

Shaun's answer is correct, however dated.

The direction of both Neo4j and Neo4jClient is towards Cypher as a unified approach to everything you need to do.

This Cypher query:

```
START root=node(0), rootFolder=node(123)
CREATE root-[:SECURITY { flags: 'W+' }]->rootFolder
```

Is this in C#:

```
client.Cypher
    .Start(new { root = client.RootNode, rootFolder })
    .Create("root-[:SECURITY {security}]->rootFolder")
    .WithParam("security", new { flags = "+W" })
    .ExecuteWithoutResults();
```

Some notes:

1. Using Cypher for this type of stuff might look a bit more complex to start with, but it will grow better for you. For example, a simple switch from `Create` to `CreateUnique` will ensure you don't create the same relationship twice; that would be much harder with the procedural approach.
2. Non-Cypher wrappers in Neo4jClient are a bit old and clunky, and will not see any significant investment moving forward
3. The C# approach uses `WithParam` to ensure that everything gets encoded properly, and you can still pass in nice objects
4. The C# approach uses `WithParam` to allow query plan caching

Comment: Mine was based on old posts that helped me figure it out. Thanks for the updated info.